# Importing old javascript with namespace from ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, namespaces

I'm converting old javascript into ES6 using babel and webpack.
In multiple files I have something like

```
var BLOG = BLOG || {};
BLOG.myClass1 = ...
```

and in another file

```
var BLOG = BLOG || {};
BLOG.myClass2 = ...
```

So, I've added `export {BLOG}` to these files, but how can I import BLOG multiple times? It seems it is not allowed, while I'd like to do something like

```
import {BLOG} from 'file1.js'
import {BLOG} from 'file2.js'
```

and have myClass1 and myClass2 into BLOG.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should export the classes, not the namespace.

Comment: The problem is that my code uses the classes like new BLOG.myClass1, so do I have to rewrite all the code??

Comment: Yes, you do.  The point of modules is to not use namespaces at all.

Comment: @cdarwin - To be fair, changing `BLOG.myClass1` to `MyClass1` (using standard naming conventions) is a really simple search-and-replace. On any \*nix, you could throw `sed` at it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, I've added `export {BLOG}` to these files, but how can I import `BLOG` multiple times?

You'd have to use different import bindings for them:

```
import {BLOG as BLOG1} from 'file1.js';
import {BLOG as BLOG2} from 'file2.js';
```

...then use `BLOG1` and `BLOG2`. Or if that bothers you, add

```
const BLOG = Object.assign({}, BLOG1, BLOG2);
```

after the imports and keep using `BLOG`.

**If** you have cyclic dependencies, it's possible that `BLOG1` and `BLOG2` may not be fully-populated right away. With true `import`/`export`, in that situation, the objects you receive will have their properties, but those properties won't be *initialized* yet. So with true `import`/`export` or a good simulation, you could use accessor properties to handle it:

```
// In a true ES2015+ module environment, or a simulated one that
// creates the properties up-front like the real one does
const BLOG = (() => {
    const b = {};
    for (const blog of [BLOG1, BLOG2]) {
        for (const key of Object.keys(blog)) {
            Object.defineProperty(b, key, {
                get(name) {
                    return blog[name];
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return b;
})();
```

*(Obviously, you'd wrap that in a function and reuse it.)*

In a simulated module environment that doesn't create the properties up-front like the real one would, you could use a proxy (though of course, if you're going to run this in a pre-ES2015 environment, it won't have `Proxy`):

```
const BLOGS = [BLOG1, BLOG2];
const BLOG = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, propName, receiver) {
    const b = BLOGS.find(b => propName in b) || target;
    return Reflect.get(b, propName, receiver);
  }
});
```

Then, properties added to `BLOG1` and `BLOG2` after-the-fact still get resolved correctly.

All of which is an ***awful lot*** of bother just to avoid the search-and-replace mentioned next.

---

***But:*** Instead of exporting `BLOG`, [as SLaks says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962624/importing-old-javascript-with-namespace-from-es6/53962648#comment94762886_53962624), export the classes, and import those. There's no need for a "namespace object" when you're using proper modules.

```
export { myClass1 };
```

and

```
export { myClass2 };
```

and then

```
import { myClass1 } from "file1.js";
import { myClass2 } from "file2.js";
```

You can even export the class as you define it, either:

```
export function myClass1() { /* ... */ }
```

or if using `class` notation:

```
export class myClass1 { /* ... */ }
```

Changing `new BLOG.myClass1` to `new MyClass1` across multiple files is a really simple search-and-replace. On *nix, you could throw `sed` at it and do an entire directory tree...

---

Side note: The **overwhelming** convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions (often loosely called "classes," e.g., functions you use with `new`) are written with an initial upper case character. E.g., `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`.

Comment: Do you agree with Slaks when he says that I have to rewrite all my code that uses calls like new BLOG.myClass1?

Comment: @cdarwin - Hit refresh. :-) You don't *have* to, but you may want to...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. How can I leave my client code unchanged if I import BLOG as BLOG1? It seems to me that I have to replace my code with new BLOG1.myClass1, am I wrong? Even if I export/import the classes without the namespace, I cannot do things like new BLOG.myClass1 but I have to do new myClass1 (rewrite my code again)

Comment: @cdarwin - Yes, you'd have to use `BLOG1.myClass1` (or do the `const BLOG = Object.assign({}, BLOG1, BLOG2);` thing I added when you raised the concern in the question comments about having to update your code). But again: Updating that code is really, really simple with any reasonable text editor (or `sed` or similar tool). You aren't *rewriting* anything. You're doing a search-and-replace.

Comment: const BLOG = Object.assign({}, BLOG1, BLOG2); is a nice suggestion, I think I'll use this. However you're right, this is search and replace, but I have the fear I could make a mess.

Comment: I tried Object.assign with no luck: the code that uses BLOG  says "BLOG.MyClass1 is not a constructor". I believe Object.assign doesn't copy correctly functions or constructors, I'm investigating

Comment: @cdarwin - `Object.assign` absolutely does copy references to functions and constructors correctly. All due respect, something *else* is wrong.

Comment: @cdarwin - I've added a note re cyclic dependencies. But I **strongly** suggest you do the search-and-replace. If you have cyclic dependencies, working around the search-and-replace is just way too much work for no gain.

Comment: Thank you. The problem, however, wasn't with Object.assign, but with variable masking as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964271/variable-masking

Answer (score 0):

You need to use import in the following manner

`{BLOG as variable name} from file`