# Variable masking

Tags: javascript, variables, bundle

I have a class defined in an index.js file like this

```
const BLOG = BLOG || {};
BLOG.ComponentFactory =  class {
}
window.BLOG = BLOG;
```

Then, in a file init.js in a bundle, I try to access that var, the file is like this

```
const BLOG = BLOG || {};
BLOG.init = function() {
    var c = new BLOG.ComponentFactory()
}
```

I get `BLOG.ComponentFactory is not a constructor` and I cannot understand why. Is the BLOG definition inside the file init.js masking the global var?

There  is something strange: using Chrome debugger in the init function, I see Blog.ComponentFactory defined inside "Global", but if I add to the properties to watch, I see Blog.ComponentFactory = undefined

I'd like to understand what's happening.

I need to defin BLOG as a global var as I'm using ES6 together with old javascritpt code.

**EDIT**: if I use the following code all works (init.js)

```
const BLOG = BLOG || {};
BLOG.init = function() {
    var c = new window.BLOG.ComponentFactory()
}
```

So, it seems the local const BLOG is masking the global BLOG var, but I need to define BLOG because otherwise I get BLOG is undefined. So, how do I solve the problem?

**EDIT2**: my webpack config (the problem is in the bundling, the vars are defined inside functions which are generated while bundling)

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

var config = {
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
    ]
  },
    // workaround for
    // ERROR in ./node_modules/wpcom/build/lib/site.media.js
  //  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/node_modules/wpcom/build/lib'
    node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
    plugins: [
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
 ]
};

var aConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "a",
    entry: "./WebContent/js/blog/index.js",
    output: {
       path: __dirname + '/WebContent/js/blogW',
       filename: "bundle.js",
       publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/js/blogW'
    },
    devServer: {
     historyApiFallback: true,
     contentBase: './WebContent',
     publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/js/blogW",
     hot: true
    }
});


module.exports = [
    aConfig
];
```

Comment: `const BLOG = BLOG || {};` shouldn't work - `BLOG was used before it was declared, which is illegal for const variables` aka `Uncaught ReferenceError: BLOG is not defined`

Comment: I don't get this error... I'm using webpack and I see that line is transformed into var BLOG = BLOG || {};

Comment: Really? That's interesting, I wonder why. Anyway, the way to solve it would be to reference `window.BLOG` instead: `const BLOG = window.BLOG || {};` but I still can't reproduce the error https://jsfiddle.net/jh0Lvgzc/ unless a `BLOG.init()` is running before the `index.js` finishes?

Comment: I'm seeing with the debugger, launched from inside init, that there is a BLOG Closure containing only init, is that masking the other Global blog? But I need to define const BLOG because I'm using it as a namespace...

Comment: init.js and index.js are bundled together, and I call BLOG.init from an index.html file. So init is run after index.js and I indeed see BLOG.ComponentFactory defined, but in the Global vars, while as I said I see also a Closure which maybe is masking the globals BLOG var

Comment: This sounds like something Webpack is doing.  You might want to post your config too.

Comment: webpack config posted

Comment: If you're using Webpack and modules, you shouldn't be doing this `var BLOG = BLOG || {}` thing **at all** (whether with `var` or with `const`, but it particularly doesn't make sense with `const`). That kind of thing is what modules are designed to fix.

Comment: *"I'm using webpack and I see that line is transformed into var BLOG = BLOG || {};"* An up-to-date transpiler would be giving you an error there: [Example](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAjAbgFAOQJk6SEAGwFMA6IkAcwAo4BKNIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.2.2&envVersion=)